# Как хранить похожие, но сильно отличающиеся сущности?

Tags: php, база-данных, laravel, проектирование

Допустим, я делаю аналог Google Forms. Там есть сущность - *Вопрос*. У *Вопросов* есть свои *Типы ответов* - радио-кнопки, чекбоксы, строка, дата и т д. Как их правильно хранить? Их можно объединить в одну сущность - *Тип ответа*, но Типы ответов очень сильно отличаются. Какому-то типу для ответа нужна просто строка, какому-то - массив. Короче, у каждого типа свои нюансы, так что в одной таблице их хранить думаю не получится. Я думаю хранить их в отдельных таблицах и создавать для них свои модели. Правильный ход мысли?)

Answer (score 1):

Возможно несколько способов для хранения и организации логики работы с *типами ответов*.

1. Полиморфные отношения между моделями.

В Laravel есть такая штука как **Polymorphic Relations**. С его помощью вы можете организовать связку `AnswerType` с конкретными моделями `RadioAnswer`, `CheckboxAnswer`, `StringAnswer` и т.д.

Внутри моделей самих конкретных ответов, для простоты работы с ними, можно было бы сделать общий для них всех интерфейс и реализовать одни и те же методы в каждой модели, что позволит учитывать специфику их отображения и обработки.

В перспективе в дальнейшем увеличить типы ответов и необходимости выводить какие-то срезы по их видам — такой подход лучше. Весь код будет разбит на отдельные файлы, а общий интерфейс позволит соблюдать единую структуру при работе с разными типами.

2. Хранить в одной модели.

В таком случае у вас по сути также может быть два поля внутри одной и той же таблицы: одно будет отвечать за тип ответа, а другое — за хранимые в этом ответе данные. При этом, второе поле, скорее всего, будет json строкой, содержащей в себе не только текст, но и дополнительные сведения, вроде массива возможных значений радио кнопок, селектов, текстового поля и т.п.

На первых порах этот подход нагляднее и проще для понимания, но приведет к раздутию модели, связанной с ним и увеличению числа встроенных в неё методов для обработки каждого вида вопроса + затраты ресурсов на постоянную конвертацию в/из JSON при обращении к объектам.